# Factorising of fourth degreee equation into linear factors

Tags: linear-algebra

Q.Factor $x^4+y^4-2x^2y^2 -5x^2 -5y^2-6xy+4=0$

I tried by hit and trial method by grouping some terms, however I am not able to find any hint for grouping which  terms.

Please  help in finding the correct thought process.

Thanks

Comment: Take $u=x+y, v=x-y$ write the whole expression as $u^2v^2-4u^2-v^2+4$ now you factorise.

Comment: @ZAhmed thanks it worked, but can  you please tell the idea  behind the substitution $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$

Comment: the uniform trick is just to pretend that $y$ is not zero, divide the whole thing by $y^4,$  then let $r = \frac{x}{y}$  and factor the single-variable $r^4 - 7 r^2 - 6 r.$ The roots $0$  and $-1$  are visible, so find   $(r^4 - 7 r^2 - 6 r)/ (r^2 + r)$